# How will I retrieve entries one by one from array and pass it on API?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, api

In the current code, I am taking data in cities and then concate with search. Search has the data in this format (Delhi,Dehradun,Kotdwara,Pune) and when I am passing it through API it is picking the first element (Delhi) and showing only its data. What I want is to pick all the cities one by one and pass them through API one by one. API will run multiple times.

````
    const [city, setCity] = useState(null);
    const [search, setSearch] = useState("");
    const [istru, setIstru] = useState(false);

    const cities = ["Delhi","Dehradun","Kotdwara","Pune"];
    if(istru==false)
    {
        
        setSearch(search.concat(cities))
        setIstru(true);
    }


    const getCity = async (search) => {
        const url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${search}&units=metric&appid=7938d9005e68d8b258a109c716436c91`;
        const response = await fetch(url);
        const resJson = await response.json();
        const city = resJson.main;
        return city;
      };
    
      const getAllCities = async() => {
        const promises = cities.map(city => getCity(city))
        const cities = await Promise.all(promises);
        // Do whatever you want with all cities
      }
    
      useEffect(() => {
        getAllCities();
      }, [cities]);


return(       
 {!city ? (
            <p className="errorMsg">Enter City Name</p>
           ) : (
            <div>
               
                <div className="info">
                <h2 className="location">
                <i className="fa-solid fa-street-view"> </i>{search}
                </h2>
                <h1 className="temp">
                {cities.temp}
                </h1>
                <h3 className="tempmin_max">
                   Min : {cities.temp_min} | Max : {cities.temp_max}
                </h3>
                </div>
)```
````

Answer (score 3):

If you want to do one by one you can do something like this:

```
 const getCity = async (search) => {
    const url = `https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${search}&units=metric&appid=7938d9005e68d8b258a109c716436c91`;
    const response = await fetch(url);
    const resJson = await response.json();
    const city = resJson.main;
    return city;
  };

  const getAllCities = async() => {
    const promises = cities.map(city => getCity(city))
    const cities = await Promise.all(promises);
    // Do whatever you want with all cities
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getAllCities();
  }, [cities]);
```

Comment: If the 'search' string variable doesn't have another purpose, this solution is suggested.

Comment: I updated the code, can you please tell me if there are more changes that need to be done?

Comment: I guess you need to call `setCity` somewhere in the code - to basically store city info and to display it. But from your post it is not clear why would you want to retrieve information about all cities and then just to store info about one city? Do you need to display info about all cities, or about one?

Comment: I want to display info of all cities.